# Define empty Bluebird promise like in Q

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

With Q I can define a new promise with:

```
var queue = q();
```

But with Bluebird if I do:

```
var queue = new Promise();
```

I get:

```
TypeError: the promise constructor requires a resolver function
```

How can I get the same result that I had with Q?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
var queue    = q()
    promises = [];
queue = queue.then(function () {
    return Main.gitControl.gitAdd(fileObj.filename, updateIndex);
});
// Here more promises are added to queue in the same way used above...
promises.push(queue);
return Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: FYI the `q` function is same as `Promise.cast` while `Promise` function is same as `q.promise`. So the equivalent of `q()` is `Promise.cast()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var resolver = Promise.defer();
setTimeout(function() {
    resolver.resolve(something); // Resolve the value
}, 5000);
return resolver.promise;
```

This line is quite often used in the [documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md).

Be aware that this is usually an anti-pattern to use that. But if you know what you're doing, `Promise.defer()` is a way to get the resolver that is similar Q's way.

**It is, however, discouraged to use this method. Bluebird has even deprecated it.**

Instead, you should use this way:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Your code
});
```

See the relevant documentation bits: [Promise.defer()](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisedefer---promiseresolver) and [new Promise()](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise).

---

After the update of your question, here is your issue: you're reusing the same promise to resolve several values. **A promise can only be resolved once.** It means you have to use `Promise.defer()` as many times as you have promises.

That said, after seeing more of your code, it seems you're really using anti-patterns. One advantage of using promises is error handling. For your case, you'd just need the following code:

```
var gitControl = Promise.promisifyAll(Main.gitControl);
var promises = [];
promises.push(gitControl.gitAddAsync(fileObj.filename, updateIndex));
return promises;
```

**This should be enough to handle your use case.** It is a lot clearer, and it also has the advantage of **really** handling the errors correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put a "FIXME" to replace the current method with the reccomended one. About the Q's way... Should I use `var resolver = Promise.defer(),queue = new Promise(resolver);`? It throws the same error.

Comment: @FezVrasta see the [progress](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#progressdynamic-value---undefined) example to see the usage of `Promise.defer()`.

Comment: I've updated my question adding a snippet of my code, I can't implement your suggested method there, I get the same error... May you help me?

Comment: @FezVrasta you're only adding one promise to your `promises` array in your example. Is that only for the sake of the example?

Comment: yes in the real code there are conditions to add more promises

Comment: Thanks, will try to apply it (https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/127)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine +1 Can you explain why `new Promise(function(...` is preferred over the use of `Promise.defer()` ? Just because it's "awkward" and "error prone" ?

Comment: I've had to switch `pending` for `defer` and `resolve` for `fulfill` in version 2.9.30

Comment: what is the use case for deferred?

Comment: Can you please remove the first half of the answer, it no longer works at all and has moved past being deprecated.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, my specific example was I was querying the database for it's information schema, which lists out the names of my columns, then I cache the value and return that instead when another request comes in later. However, if I suddenly got 500 hits to that one async function and there was no previous entry in the cache, it would queue up 500 redundant queries. So now, I make 1 real query, and push 499 resolves, and when that 1 query returns, resolve the other 499 wiht the same data

Answer (score 37):

Florian provided a good answer For the sake of your original question, there are several ways to start a chain with Bluebird.

One of the simplest is calling `Promise.resolve()` on nothing:

```
var queue = Promise.resolve(); //resolve a promise with nothing or cast a value
```

or

```
Promise.try(function(...){
    return ...//chain here
});
```

So you can do:

```
var queue    = Promise.resolve()
    promises = [];
queue = queue.then(function () {
    return Main.gitControl.gitAdd(fileObj.filename, updateIndex);
});

// Here more promises are added to queue in the same way used above...
promises.push(queue);
return Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
   // ...
});
```

Although, personally I'd do something like:

```
//arr is your array of fileObj and updateIndex

Promise.map(arr,function(f){ return Main.gitControl.gitAdd(f.filename,f.updateIndex).
    then (function(result){
        //results here
    });
```

Comment: If you want each gitAdd to wait for the next, you should use `Promise.reduce` instead of `Promise.map`.

Comment: Why is `Promise.resolve()` better than `Promise.cast()`?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine good quesiton, Promsie.resolve is in the ES6 spec, when the API was created Promise.cast and Promise.resolve were both in the ES6 spec and Bluebird, I assume that `.cast` is going to be dropped in Bluebird 2.0.

Comment: Both `Bluebird.defer()` and `Bluebird.cast()` are deprecated in 2.x versions, and to start a "clean" promise chain, it's better to use `Bluebird.resolve()`

Comment: @pocesar that is correct, I'll remove the `.cast` as we deprecated it in 2.0 (or even 1.X iirc), where am I missing the `.defer` here?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum nowhere, just making note that both are deprecated :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as I had a method which fetches a resource on the internet and returns the content, but I want it to handle connection timeouts and retrying up to X times with delays between.

As `Bluebird.defer` is deprecated, I used this which does this trick:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var fetch = function (options, promise) {
    var resolve, reject;
    if (promise) {
        resolve = promise.resolve;
        reject = promise.reject;
        promise = promise.promise;
    } else {
        promise = new Promise(function () {
            resolve = arguments[0];
            reject = arguments[1];
        });
    }
    var retry = {promise: promise, resolve: resolve, reject: reject};

    // Your logic here that you want to retry
    if (typeof options.x === 'undefined') {
        reject(new Error('X not defined'));
    } else if (options.x < 3) {
        options.x++;
        options.retryAttempt = (options.retryAttempt || 0) + 1;
        console.log(`Retrying in 1 second attempt ${options.retryAttempt}...`);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(options, retry)
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        resolve(options.x);
    }

    return promise;
}

fetch({x:0})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a pattern like this useful for any kind of integration testing.

```
const responseResolver;

const response = new Promise(resolve => {
    responseResolver = resolve;
}).then(data => {
    console.log("data: ", data);
    return data;
});

// mock some method that returns a promise (e.g. waits for a response)
service.getIceCreams = () => response;

// do some assertions while the response is pending

responseResolver("cookie dough"); // will trigger .then: "data: cookie dough"

// do some assertions now that the response is completed
```