# Mongodb iterate a collection of in a synchronous way using promises

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I have a method (see code example) and I'm trying to return a promises list to parent method. My problem is when pushing promises in my promiseList array.

*getDistance* is a method returning a Promise. If I do *.then()* in getDistance method,everything is OK. Nevertheless, if I try to push the promise into my array, when I do .then in parent method, it is empty.

I think it may happen due to *each* loop is asynchronous...

```
var promiseList = [];
    res = db.collection.find query statement... 
    res.each(function(err, doc) {
        if (doc!==null) {
            promiseList.push(
                 getDistance(orgLat, orgLon, destLat, desLon)
            );
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(promTimeList);
```

I'm using MongoDB as database, and NodeJS in server side, with mongodb as driver to connecto to my database and Bluebird as library to implement promises.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know when `each` has finished?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct in that the issue is due to the fact that `each` is asynchronous. You can use `defer` to wrap callback APIs (like `each`) into promises. It would work something like this:

```
res = db.collection.find query statement... 
processResponse(res)
    .then(function(promiseList) {
        // execute all the promises
        return Promise.all(promiseList);
    }, function (err) {
        // handle error
    });    

function processResponse(res) {
    var deferred = Promise.pending();
    var promiseList = [];
    res.each(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // error, abort
            deferred.reject(err);
            return;
        }
        else if (doc != null) {
            promiseList.push(
                getDistance(orgLat, orgLon, destLat, desLon)
            );
        }
        else {
           // finished looping through all results, return the promise list
           deferred.resolve(promiseList);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

See more on `defer` with bluebird at the following link (look for "So when should deferred be used?"):

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

**Update**: According to this post:

[Define empty Bluebird promise like in Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684643/define-empty-bluebird-promise-like-in-q)

It looks like there is a Promise constructor that may be the preferred way to do this. The `processResponse` method would look like this:

```
function processResponse(res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var promiseList = [];
        res.each(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                // error, abort
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            else if (doc != null) {
                promiseList.push(
                    getDistance(orgLat, orgLon, destLat, desLon)
                );
            }
            else {
               // finished looping through all results, return the promise list
               resolve(promiseList);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks to @Bergi. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am more familiar with the Q library (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) than bluebird.

Comment: Yes, you really should use the `Promise` constructor instead of a deferred here.

Comment: Oh. Is that what you are referring to? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684643/define-empty-bluebird-promise-like-in-q - I am not very familiar with bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the collection syncrhonously by using `await` with `cursor.next()` in a `while` loop:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({});

while ((doc = await cursor.next()) != null) {
        promiseList.push(
             getDistance(doc.orgLat, doc.orgLon, doc.destLat, doc.desLon);
        );
}
```